# How do i supply "rootelement" option while testing protractor interatively

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end

When I execute `node elementexplorer.js http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/view1`

I get the following error:

> There was a webdriver error: Error Error while waiting for Protractor
>   to sync with the page: "root element (body) has no injector. this may
>   mean it is not inside ng-app."

Please let me know how to provide the `rootelement` option.

Answer (score 9):

At the moment, rootElement defaults to body. If you don't have your ng-app in the body, you will get that error. It can be set manually tho.

You need to change the rootElement. You can do it directly from the interactive view by running:

```
browser.rootEl = 'div#ng-app-located-here';
```

Assuming that your ng-app is located at `div#ng-app-located-here`

Answer (score 5):

In this case, you need to specify on which element your `ng-app` is set. Add `rootElement` in your protractor `conf.js`, for example:

```
rootElement: 'div#nested-ng-app'  // by default, it is 'body'
```

FYI, this is because protractor angular-specific custom locators, like `by.binding` or `by.model` use `rootElement` as a root for the search, quote from the [change log](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/29ce5c6ad0d24d06f03f0a7736af4f6a91d4bf3f/CHANGELOG.md#bug-fixes-5):

> Protractor's custom locators (by.binding, by.model, etc) use
>   config.rootElement as the root for all their searches. This meant that
>   config.rootElement was used both to specify how to get hold of
>   Angular's injector as well as where to begin searching for elements.
>   This does not work for all cases, for example if a dialog should be
>   searched for elements but is a sibling, not a child, of ng-app.