# Protractor change rootEl after start when testing angular app

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I setup my protractor with this conf file below:

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'mocha',
  rootElement: '#container1',
  specs: ['*container1_spec.js'],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    version: '',
    platform: 'ANY'
  },
  onPrepare: function() {
    // implicit and page load timeouts
    browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40000);
    browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25000);
  }
}
```

The application is manually bootstrapped in angular and I need to **change the root element after some steps when the application transfers the control to another application** by doing a `window.location.replace`. The second application that starts is also an angular app which does manual bootstrapping.

From [another thread in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28836134/how-do-i-supply-rootelement-option-while-testing-protractor-interatively). I found the code that I could do `browser.rootEl = 'div#container2';`

```
WebDriverError: unknown error: [ng:test] no injector found for element argument to getTestability
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ng/test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the question, changing the rootEl did not work. I had to resort to working with the DOM to run the tests.

```
function getMessage() {
  return document.getElementById('msg').textContent;
}
setTimeout(function() {
  browser.executeScript(getMessage).then(function (txt) {
    chai.expect(txt).to.equal("Error occured");
    done();
  });
}, 10000);
```

`browser.executeScript` is the key function that allowed me to query DOM and workaround. I had to add a timeout for the lag to allow the second application to download and bootstrap.